# Loading another component other then App component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6, angular7

**I want to load FleshScreenComponent component in Angular project at first by replacing Appcomponent so for that I am doing it by**

```
 bootstrap: [FleshScreenComponent],
```

but still I am not able to do it

for the I am putting my full code from app.module.ts file.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule }    from '@angular/common/http';
import { LoginComponent} from './LoginComponent/LoginComponent.component';
import { FleshScreenComponent} from './FleshScreenComponent/FleshScreenComponent.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,

    LoginComponent,
    FleshScreenComponent,


  ],
  imports: [

  ],
  entryComponents:[
    LoginComponent, PaymentComponent
  ],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
  providers: [ServicesService ,CommonStorageService,  {provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} }],
  bootstrap: [FleshScreenComponent],

})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: is there any error you face in ng serve or dev console?

Comment: @Sivaramakrishnan I am grtting erroe ->>>>>: The selector "app-FleshScreen" did not match any elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look  [at this demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-suxx88?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

You need to provide the selector of `FleshScreenComponent` in `index.html` something like what I have done in my demo for `HelloComponent`

```
<hello>loading</hello>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Routes to load the required component when application starts. This would give the application a better structure.

put this in app-routing.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [{
path : '',
component : FleshScreenComponent
}];

and this in app.component.html

```
<router-outlet>
</router-outlet>
```

Lastly, don't forget to import your routing module in app.module as I see this import is missing from your code.

Answer (score -1):

Inside the AppComponent's ngOnInit method, you could programatically redirect to your FleshScreenComponent if you are using routing.

Comment: I can do that but I want to load another component

Comment: Which component do you want to load?

Comment: FleshScreenComponent

Comment: That is what you could redirect to in the Appcomponent. Doing that it loads your component instead of appcomnponent

Comment: This is not an answer @TestingAnurag is looking for. If you have this suggestion, put it on comment and not as answer

Comment: This is a matter of understanding. It is a perfect answer I am currently using.